# Limit attempt read file only several times

Tags: python, python-3.5

I want to make a limit (say three times) to the attempts when trying to open file and the file cannot be found.

```
while True:
    inputfilename = input('Type the filename then press enter: ')
    try:
        inputfile  = open(inputfilename,"r", newline='')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print ('File does not exist')
        print ('')
    else:
        break
```

The result of the code above, there is no limit. How can I put the limit in the above codes. 
I am using python 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `while True:` by `for _ in range(3):`

`_` is a variable name (could by `i` as well). By convention this name means you are deliberately not using this variable in the code below. It is a "throwaway" variable.

`range` (`xrange` in python 2.7+) is a sequence object that generates (lazily) a sequence between 0 and the number given as argument.

Comment: yes sorry xrange was replaced by range in python 3. Fixing my answer

Answer (score 2):

Loop three times over a range breaking if you successfully open the file:

```
for _ in range(3):
    inputfilename = input('Type the filename then press enter: ')
    try:
        inputfile  = open(inputfilename,"r", newline='')
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print ('File does not exist')
        print ('')
```

Or put it in a function:

```
def try_open(tries):
    for _ in range(tries):
        inputfilename = input('Type the filename then press enter: ')
        try:
            inputfile = open(inputfilename, "r", newline='')
            return inputfile
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('File does not exist')
            print('')
    return False


f =  try_open(3)
if f:
    with f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a while loop then the following code works.

```
count = 0
while count < 3:
    inputfilename = input('Type the filename then press enter: ')
    try:
        inputfile  = open(inputfilename,"r", newline='')
        count += 1
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print ('File does not exist')
        print ('')
```